# Keras Deep Learning - Output prediction is a different shape to the input raster

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to run a script using [Keras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keras) [deep learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning). It has been an uphill battle so far, but I've been able to train a model :) Note the model was trained with 3D RGB arrays, with each patch being 125x125 pixels wide.

The training went well, but now when I apply the model to data, the model returns errors. When I configure the datashape (added an extra dimension at the start), it runs, but it produces an output in the entirely wrong shape. Here is the output from model.summary() and model.inputs:

```
model.summary()
Model: "model_13"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #  Connected to
==================================================================================================
 input_4 (InputLayer)            [(None, 128, 128, 3  0        []
                                 )]

 block1_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 64  1792     ['input_4[0][0]']
                                 )

 block1_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 64  36928    ['block1_conv1[0][0]']
                                 )

 block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 64, 64, 64)   0        ['block1_conv2[0][0]']

 block2_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 128)  73856    ['block1_pool[0][0]']

 block2_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 128)  147584   ['block2_conv1[0][0]']

 block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 32, 32, 128)  0        ['block2_conv2[0][0]']

 block3_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 256)  295168   ['block2_pool[0][0]']

 block3_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 256)  590080   ['block3_conv1[0][0]']

 block3_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 256)  590080   ['block3_conv2[0][0]']

 block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 16, 16, 256)  0        ['block3_conv3[0][0]']

 block4_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 512)  1180160  ['block3_pool[0][0]']

 block4_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 512)  2359808  ['block4_conv1[0][0]']

 block4_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 512)  2359808  ['block4_conv2[0][0]']

 block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 8, 8, 512)    0        ['block4_conv3[0][0]']

 zero_padding2d_4 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 10, 10, 512)  0        ['block4_pool[0][0]']
 D)

 conv2d_27 (Conv2D)              (None, 8, 8, 512)    2359808  ['zero_padding2d_4[0][0]']

 batch_normalization_4 (BatchNo  (None, 8, 8, 512)    2048     ['conv2d_27[0][0]']
 rmalization)

 up_sampling2d_7 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 16, 16, 512)  0        ['batch_normalization_4[0][0]']

 concatenate_7 (Concatenate)     (None, 16, 16, 768)  0        ['up_sampling2d_7[0][0]',
                                                               'block3_pool[0][0]']

 zero_padding2d_5 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 18, 18, 768)  0        ['concatenate_7[0][0]']
 D)

 conv2d_28 (Conv2D)              (None, 16, 16, 256)  1769728  ['zero_padding2d_5[0][0]']

 batch_normalization_5 (BatchNo  (None, 16, 16, 256)  1024     ['conv2d_28[0][0]']
 rmalization)

 up_sampling2d_8 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 32, 32, 256)  0        ['batch_normalization_5[0][0]']

 concatenate_8 (Concatenate)     (None, 32, 32, 384)  0        ['up_sampling2d_8[0][0]',
                                                               'block2_pool[0][0]']

 zero_padding2d_6 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 34, 34, 384)  0        ['concatenate_8[0][0]']
 D)

 conv2d_29 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 128)  442496   ['zero_padding2d_6[0][0]']

 batch_normalization_6 (BatchNo  (None, 32, 32, 128)  512      ['conv2d_29[0][0]']
 rmalization)

 up_sampling2d_9 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 64, 64, 128)  0        ['batch_normalization_6[0][0]']

 concatenate_9 (Concatenate)     (None, 64, 64, 192)  0        ['up_sampling2d_9[0][0]',
                                                               'block1_pool[0][0]']

 zero_padding2d_7 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 66, 66, 192)  0        ['concatenate_9[0][0]']
 D)

 conv2d_30 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 64)   110656   ['zero_padding2d_7[0][0]']

 batch_normalization_7 (BatchNo  (None, 64, 64, 64)   256      ['conv2d_30[0][0]']
 rmalization)

 conv2d_31 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 2)    1154     ['batch_normalization_7[0][0]']

 reshape_3 (Reshape)             (None, 4096, 2)      0        ['conv2d_31[0][0]']

 activation_3 (Activation)       (None, 4096, 2)      0        ['reshape_3[0][0]']

==================================================================================================
Total params: 12,322,946
Trainable params: 12,321,026
Non-trainable params: 1,920
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

model.inputs
Out[52]: [<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 128, 128, 3) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'input_4')>]
```

And here are the input and output shapes:

```
val_data.shape
Out[53]: (1, 128, 128, 3)

out.shape
Out[54]: TensorShape([1, 4096, 2])
```

I notice that the out shape is the same as the final two "Output Shape" values for the model summary, so I think this has something to do with it. However, this is where I am stuck. I do not know enough about TensorFlow or Keras to resolve this problem.

Comment: The output shape must match the function requirement, (None 2)

Comment: Does the current answer have any merit? Or is it completely bogus? (Not rhetorical questions.)

Answer (score -2):

First you need to understand the loss functions. It is compared or label prediction with the label you remarked as true for simple. See the custom_loss_function class that is different by each type. You can apply root mean square or SoftMax from its differentiate.

Sample: An example using a custom loss function and examining why the label shape needs to be the format (None, 10) or (1, 2) or anything that matches the loss function you selected.

```
import tensorflow as tf

import pandas as pd

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
variables = pd.read_excel('F:\\temp\\Python\\excel\\Book 13 (2) (3).xlsx', index_col=None, header=[0])

list_label = [ ]
list_Image = [ ]
list_file_actual = [ ]
list_label_actual = [ 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy' ]

for Index, Image, Label in variables.values:
    print( Label )
    image = tf.io.read_file( Image )
    image = tf.io.decode_image(image)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_Image.append(image)

    if Label == 0:
        list_label.append(0)
    else:
        list_label.append(9)

list_label = tf.cast( list_label, dtype=tf.int32 )
list_label = tf.constant( list_label, shape=( 54, 1, 1 ) )
list_Image = tf.cast( list_Image, dtype=tf.int32 )
list_Image = tf.constant( list_Image, shape=( 54, 1, 32, 32, 3 ) )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class Custom_Loss_Function(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        log_y_pred = tf.math.log(y_pred)
        log_y_pred = tf.cast( log_y_pred, dtype=tf.float32 )
        y_true = tf.cast( y_true, dtype=tf.float32 )

        elements = -tf.math.multiply_no_nan(x=log_y_pred, y=y_true)
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(elements,axis=1))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(( list_Image, list_label ))
list_Image = tf.constant( list_Image, shape=( 54, 32, 32, 3) ).numpy()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 3 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
])
model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
lossfn = Custom_Loss_Function()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=10000 )
```

Output: To see the model summarize and running of our custom loss function.

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 normalization (Normalizatio  (None, 32, 32, 3)        0
 n)

 normalization_1 (Normalizat  (None, 32, 32, 3)        0
 ion)

 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 30, 30, 32)        896

 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 15, 15, 32)       0
 )

 dense (Dense)               (None, 15, 15, 128)       4224

 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 128, 225)          0

 bidirectional (Bidirectiona  (None, 128, 192)         247296
 l)

 bidirectional_1 (Bidirectio  (None, 192)              221952
 nal)

 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 192)               0

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 192)               37056

 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1930

=================================================================
Total params: 513,354
Trainable params: 513,354
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10000
2022-12-09 16:19:18.626253: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:368] Loaded cuDNN version 8100
46/54 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0217
```

Sample: Find the alignment of two pictures

```
var1 = tf.Variable(255.0, dtype=tf.dtypes.float64)
var2 = tf.Variable(10.0, dtype=tf.dtypes.float64)
X_var = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('X', dtype = tf.float64, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.dtypes.float64))
y_var = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('Y', dtype = tf.float64, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.dtypes.float64))
Z = tf.nn.l2_loss((var1 - X_var) ** 2 + (var2 - y_var) ** 2, name="loss")

loss = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(Z))
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

previous_train_loss = 0
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
    image = list_file[0]
    X = image
    Y = image

    for i in range(1000):
        global_step = global_step + 1
        train_loss, temp = sess.run([loss, training_op], feed_dict={X_var:X, y_var:Y})
        history.append( train_loss )

        if global_step % 2 == 0 :
            var2 = var2 - 0.001
        if global_step % 4 == 0 and train_loss <=  previous_train_loss :
            var1 = var1 - var2 + 0.5
        print( 'steps: ' + str(i) )
        print( 'train_loss: ' + str(train_loss) )

        previous_train_loss = train_loss
```

Output: Because they are the same picture!

[image: Sample]